# Fetching Cart Products from the Server According to ID - Node.Js/Mongodb/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I tried to fetched data(more than one) from mongo db database according to the id and it doesn't work. I'll be thankful to you If you can help me to fix that issue.

```
static fetchCart(itemArr){
    const userCart = [...itemArr]
    const db = getDb();
    const fetchedCart = [];
    for (var i=0; i<userCart.length; i++){
      const item = userCart[i];
      db.collection("products")
      .findOne({ _id: new mogoDb.ObjectId(item.productId) })
      .then((prod) => {
        fetchedCart.push(prod);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    return fetchedCart;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Query for searching array of ids

```
db.collection.find( { _id : { $in : [1,2,3,4] } } );
```

Comment: kindly don't use loop

Comment: If array looks as follows, what can I do
[
  { productId: new ObjectId("1"), qty: 2 },
  { productId: new ObjectId("2"), qty: 1 }
]